# Strange error in ModelSim but not in Quartus?

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I'm doing a Verilog project on quartus, and when I do the analysis and synthesis, quartus doesn't give me any errors.

When instead I try to compile the files on ModelSim, it gives me the following error:

> ** Error: C:/Users/deivi/OneDrive/Documents/ingegneria_progetti/EMBEDDED/prima_esercitazione/Gestione_sensori/conta_periodo.v(90):
> A begin/end block was found with an empty body.  This is permitted in
> SystemVerilog, but not permitted in Verilog.  Please look for any
> stray semicolons.

```
module conta_periodo (avvia, fatto, enable , start_count, ck, rst_l,rst_sync);
    input avvia, rst_l, ck, enable;
    
    output reg start_count, fatto, rst_sync;
    reg [2:0] s_reg, s_next;
    parameter [2:0] s_i = 3'b000, s_1 = 3'b001, s_2 = 3'b010, s_3 = 3'b011;
    initial s_reg = 3'b000;
    
    always @ (posedge ck) // memoria di stato
        begin

            if (rst_l) s_reg <= s_i;
        
            else
            
            begin
            
            if (enable) s_reg <= s_next;
            else s_reg <= s_reg;
            
            end
        end
    
    always @ (*)
        begin
            s_next = s_reg;
            case (s_reg)
            
                s_i: 
                        if (avvia) s_next = s_1;
                        else s_next = s_i;
                        
                s_1: s_next = s_2;
                        
                        
                s_2: s_next = s_3;
                        
                s_3:  s_next = s_i;
                
                
            
                default: s_next = s_i;
                
            endcase
        end

    always @ (s_reg)
        begin 
            
            
            
            case (s_reg)
                s_i: begin
                            start_count = 1'b0;
                            fatto =1'b0;
                            rst_sync=1'b1;
                            
                        end
                s_1: begin
                            start_count = 1'b1;
                            fatto =1'b0;
                            rst_sync=1'b1;
                            
                        end
                s_2: begin
                            start_count = 1'b1;
                            fatto =1'b0;
                            rst_sync=1'b1;
                            
                        end
                        
                        
                s_3: begin
                            start_count = 1'b0;
                            fatto =1'b1;
                            rst_sync=1'b0;
                            
                        end
                        
                
                        
                        
                default: begin
                start_count = 1'b0;
                            fatto =1'b0;
                            rst_sync=1'b0;
                            
                end
                
                    endcase;
        end
endmodule
```

It's a state machine that works with another block.

Does anyone know why I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:

> Please look for any stray semicolons.

There is a stray semicolon on line 90, as reported in the error message.  Change:

```
                endcase;
```

to:

```
                endcase
```

You should not add semicolons after "end"-type keywords like `end`, `endcase`, `endmodule`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error in Modelsim, but not Quartus is because Modelsim interprets files with a `*.v` suffix using older Verilog language syntax rules  by default. Quartus might have a different language  default. Verilog does not have the concept of a null statement( a bare semi-colon `;` ). Block statements like `begin/end`,`case/endcase` are complete statements that do not need a terminating `;`.